# How to pass a js variable to the controller in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am sending an `id` in my js code and I want to pass that variable to my controller. Any advice on how I can do that?

```
<input class="btn_confirm" type="submit" id={i} 
       onclick="id_click(this.id)" value="Delete" />
```

```
var id;
function id_click(clicked_id) {
    id = clicked_id;
}
```

I tried different things but nothing worked out.

Answer (score 0):

I tried as below：

Model：

```
    public class ReceiveModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SomeKey { get; set; }
    }
```

View：

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form id="form" asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="1" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="2" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="3" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
        
    </div>
</div>



<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>    
    $("input[type='submit']").click(function ()
    {
        var tempid = this.id
        var tmpInput = $("<input type='text' name='SomeKey' hidden/>");
        tmpInput.attr("value", tempid );
        var form = $("#form")
        form.append(tmpInput)
        form.submit()
    })
</script>
```

Result：

[image]

Comment: I dont understand the part with the model class. Why do you create two classes?

Comment: Oh,sorry,The first model was not necessary,and  I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can lookup API requests. If you want to send one parameter as a primitive type (string, integer, etc.) you can use query strings in your API calls. For example, let's assume you have an API endpoint like this: `localhost:5000/api/YourController`. You can send params via API get calls like this `localhost:5000/api/YourController?yourParam=<param-value>`. In this example your API call type is `GET`.

If you want to send complex types (like classes, objects) to your controller you can lookup POST API requests.

You can find more details in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio).